# mysql display each type in row and group by date range

Tags: mysql, datetime, count, pivot-table

I am not sure this data structure able to do the result I want. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84939

This is the data, please ignore the duration column.

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------+------+
| id | created_date        | start_date          | end_date            | duration | status | type |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------+------+
|  1 | 2016-04-05 15:23:29 | 2016-08-15 10:21:53 | 2016-08-19 00:00:00 |       30 |      1 |    2 |
|  2 | 2016-04-06 15:23:29 | 2016-08-15 10:21:53 | 2016-08-19 00:00:00 |       30 |      1 |    1 |
|  3 | 2016-04-06 15:23:29 | 2016-08-15 10:21:53 | 2016-08-19 00:00:00 |       30 |      1 |    3 |
|  4 | 2016-04-06 15:23:29 | 2016-08-17 10:21:53 | 2016-08-19 00:00:00 |       30 |      1 |    1 |
|  5 | 2016-04-06 15:23:29 | 2016-08-17 09:21:53 | 2016-08-19 00:00:00 |       30 |      1 |    1 |
|  6 | 2016-04-06 15:23:29 | 2016-08-01 09:21:53 | 2016-08-31 00:00:00 |       30 |      1 |    1 |
|  7 | 2016-04-06 15:23:29 | 2016-08-01 09:21:53 | 2016-08-31 00:00:00 |       30 |      0 |    1 |
|  8 | 2016-04-06 15:23:29 | 2016-08-15 09:21:53 | 2016-08-16 00:00:00 |       30 |      1 |    2 |
|  9 | 2016-04-06 15:23:29 | 2016-08-16 09:21:53 | 2016-08-17 00:00:00 |       30 |      1 |    3 |
| 10 | 2016-04-06 15:23:29 | 2016-08-19 09:21:53 | 2016-08-20 00:00:00 |       30 |      1 |    2 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------+------+
```

I want to filter the report from 2016-08-15 until 2016-08-19. for 2015-08-19 even 00:00:00, I am not sure consider count or not. But for my example. I just count it because it is in the range.
This is the summary done by me manually:-

```
(type-2)15,16,17,18,19
(type-1)15,16,17,18,19
(type-3)15,16,17,18,19
(type-1)17,18,19
(type-1)17,18,19
(type-1)15,16,17,18,19
(type-1)15,16,17,18,19
(type-2)15,16
(type-3)16,17
(type-2)19,20
```

This is the result I would like to generate in sql return data.

```
+------------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| date       | ct_all | ct_type_1 | ct_type_2 | ct_type_3 |
+------------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 2016-08-15 | 6      | 3         | 2         | 1         |
| 2016-08-16 | 7      | 3         | 2         | 2         |
| 2016-08-17 | 8      | 5         | 1         | 2         |
| 2016-08-18 | 7      | 5         | 1         | 1         |
| 2016-08-19 | 8      | 5         | 2         | 1         |
+------------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

ct_all = count all

ct_type_1 = count total for type 1

As long as the type fall into start_date and end_date then it will count.
Normally we done search date is base on one column type, e.g created_date. and I can use between >= and <= to find the range. But this one got start and end date. Not sure can be accomplished or not.

Comment: You have to have a table with all existing dates (see e.g. [Calendar Tables: An Invaluable Database Tool](http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables)). Join this with your data on `>= start_date`  and `<= end_date`. This you can just count then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three different things going on here.

1. an enumeration of days.
2. a `DATETIME` range filter.
3. a so-called pivot, pivoting rows by type into columns.

It's helpful to take these one at a time.

First, I guess you have five days you wish to filter, [15-Aug-2016 - 19-Aug-2016] inclusive. You want to make a list of all those days. This little query will do that. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84939/21/0)

```
    SELECT CONVERT('2016-08-15' + INTERVAL seq DAY, DATETIME) AS CURDATE
        FROM (SELECT 0 AS SEQ UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2
                              UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
             ) seq_0_to_4
```

(Notice something: The [MariaDB fork of MySQL](https://mariadb.com/) has [sequence tables like `seq_0_to_4` built in](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sequence/) so you don't have to do all this `UNION ALL` stuff.)

Second, you want to get a list of the `type` values occurring on each day. You can get that to happen with a LEFT JOIN, like so (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84939/26/0).

```
 SELECT seq.curdate, record.type
   FROM (

          SELECT CONVERT('2016-08-15' + INTERVAL seq DAY, DATETIME) AS CURDATE
            FROM (SELECT 0 AS SEQ UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2
                                  UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
                 ) seq_0_to_4
       ) seq
  LEFT JOIN record ON seq.curdate >= DATE(record.start_date)
                  AND seq.curdate <= DATE(record.end_date)
```

This gives you a list of `curdate` and `type` values.

The `ON` condition of that join chooses `record` rows that start on or before each date, and end anytime on each date.

Finally, you need to do a `pivot` operation to summarize the counts of type values.  That looks something like this. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84939/28/0)

```
 SELECT curdate, 
        COUNT(type) ct_all,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ct_1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ct_2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ct_3
   FROM (the above query) d
  GROUP BY curdate
  ORDER BY curdate
```

This is a case where the *structured* part of Structured Query Language is necessary.

Comment: I can't imagine it can be done. seq_0_to_4 something new I learn from mysql knowledge. Thanks Ollie Jones! Awesome explanation from you! Appreciated!